# Bootstrap checkbox buttons don't highlight as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use this example on the bootstrap webiste:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio

The buttons, even in this example, don't highlight properly when they are clicked.
For example, click an unchecked button. You'll see that it highlights dark blue. Then, if you click it again to deselect it, the button stays highlighted! until you click another button or click outside the button group. (play around with the buttons, clicking buttons and the white space outside the button group, and you'll see what I mean)

This formatting isn't useful for a user if they don't know what buttons are checked/unchecked as soon as they click a button.

Is there a way to fix this, so that the button is highlighted properly immediately after clicking?